# lwheel and rwheel frame to link up to URDF

Tags: ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, this seem to be the final thing I am stuck on, please help

My wheels in my URDF is lwheel and rwheel

When I list topics, the wheels are listed

```
/rwheel
/rwheel_vel
/rwheel_vtarget
```

When I do rosrun tf view_frames

```
Exception thrown:"odom" passed to lookupTransform argument source_frame does not exist.  
The current list of frames is: 
Frame laser exists with parent base_frame. 
Frame base_frame exists with parent map. 
Frame scanmatcher_frame exists with parent
```

What the hell do I need to map these so the URDF maps to the publisher?  I think its something to do with a TF?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254539/lwheel-and-rwheel-frame-to-link-up-to-urdf/) by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 202 on 2017-02-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-02-13**:
If you have a URDF describing the geometry of your robot (e.g. the transform between `base_link` and `lwheel`) then you likely need to be running an instance of the [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) which publishes the /tf data between the links in a URDF

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-13**:
First thank you for answer, you rock.  My base_link is actually base_frame (seems Hector Mapping uses that) however everything is linked (base_frame, lwheel, rwheel, laser etc)  Laser and Base_frame come up fine in RVIZ.  lwheel, rwheel do not? ]

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-02-13**:
Do lwheel and rwheel have non-fixed joints? For example continuous rotation joints about the axle axis? If so, something needs to publish a [sensor_msgs/JointState](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/JointState.html) message, typically on the `/joints_states` topic, containing these angles

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-02-13**:
You may be interested in using the [joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) to help get these values published.

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-13**:
I was following the URDF tutorial and so the wheels are just connected to the Base_frame http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive/tutorials/setup_urdf

**Comment by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) on 2017-02-13**:
Tonight I will try the code again with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the bit I needed to add as mentioned above was:

This seems to advertises the parts of the robot URDF(joints etc) to RVIZ.  The errors went away

---

Originally posted by [burf2000](https://answers.ros.org/users/28716/burf2000/) with karma: 202 on 2017-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0